# Source for U.S. government reports 1900-1950?

Tags: government, historical

I am researching the history of the motion picture industry and seeking U.S. government reports and documents from major departments (especially Commerce, State) for the period of 1900-1950. I'm looking for online archives containing PDFs of that kind of material.

Is that material available in any academic databases, open data repositories, or other sources?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

- **Records of the Department of State** here: https://www.archives.gov/research/foreign-policy/state-dept/agency-records
  (Contains inventories of physical archives but no scans of primary sources.)
- [Proquest Congressional](https://about.proquest.com/libraries/academic/databases/proquest-congressional.html) contains historical archives of government docs. (Not an open source.)

(More updates to come)